# Reputation audit seems not to notice the day has ended

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-audit

I have noticed this interesting behaviour of the reputation audit: if I hit the rep cap, the `rep cap was reached` counter is incremented immediately. However, the `rep cap was exceeded` counter only gets incremented after my first rep change *the next day*. For example, this is what I saw today morning:

```
...
-- 2010-06-01 rep +262  = 15495     

** total rep 15495 :)

days represented 114
rep cap was reached on 22 days
rep cap was exceeded on 31 days
```

And then, after downvoting an answer:

```
...
-- 2010-06-01 rep +262  = 15495     
 3   2955997 (-1)
-- 2010-06-02 rep -1    = 15494     

** total rep 15494 :)

days represented 115
rep cap was reached on 22 days
rep cap was exceeded on 32 days
```

Note that the behaviour is not specific to downvotes - I have observed the same with upvotes too. Today it just happened so that my first rep change for the day was a downvote.

It's not a big issue, but is surprising to me, as I would expect the two counters are calculated in a similar way. I would be interested to know the logic behind - is this "by design" or "by chance" ?

**Update:** now that I refreshed my audit, it is actually back to its earlier state - apparently the answer I downvoted got deleted as spam :-)

**Update2:** with S.Mark's upvote and another one, now it looks like this:

```
...
-- 2010-06-01 rep +262  = 15495     
 2   2932490 (10)
 2   2956451 (10)
-- 2010-06-02 rep +20   = 15515     

** total rep 15515 :)

days represented 115
rep cap was reached on 22 days
rep cap was exceeded on 32 days
```

Comment: I've upvoted one of your answer, so check it again, you should see 32 days on exceeded.

Comment: @S.Mark, thanks, it does indeed. Btw as I got another upvote in the meantime, feel free to remove yours :-)

Answer (score 1):

> However, the rep cap was exceeded counter only gets incremented after my first rep change *the next day*.

I've noticed this and always thought that it was [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). I assumed that a script runs that checks your daily reputation is > 200 and due to down-votes (both given and received), removal of up-votes, acceptances (given, received and taken away) this isn't stable until after the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I think `rep cap exceeded` is not calculated for last record, so you need + or - votes on next day. This could be bug, but I am not sure about that, I noticed that behavior for a while ago.